# Embed Ember app in existing Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ember.js

Is there a way to embed Ember application in existing Angular application (or vice versa)?

Does anybody have experience with this?

I know there is a way in Ember to define `rootElement` of the application (which defaults to `body`), but I don't know what needs to be done on both sides to make this work.

Comment: Is this question `opinion-based`? How? The question is valid.

Comment: how come this question is  opinion-based? this is a valid great question, which is no where near to being based on opinions. The question is put on hold mistakenly in my opinion!